# Why can't the compiler infer the type for this select call?

Tags: c#, linq, type-inference

I'm trying to create a list of ViewModels out of a DTO by calling a select on the list of DTO's.
However, the compiler gives me an error saying:

**The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage try specifying the type arguments**

My question is, why can't it? Both `TextSectionDTO` and `ImageSectionDTO` are derived from `SectionDTO`. I'm trying to create a `List` of `Sections`, and both `TextSection` and `ImageSection` are derived from `Section`.

I know this question is close to some other questions posted on here, but I wasn't able to find an answer there.

This is my code:

```
private List<Section> BuildSectionViewModel(IEnumerable<SectionDTO> ss )
{
    var viewModels = ss.Select((SectionDTO s) =>
    {
        switch (s.SectionType)
        {
            case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyText:
                return new TextSection((TextSectionDTO) s);
            case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyImage:
                return new ImageSection((ImageSectionDTO) s);
            default:
                throw new Exception("This section does not exist - FIXME");
        }
    }).ToList();

    return viewModels;
}
```

When I change the types so that I only accept superclass SectionDTO and only return Section (I make them both normal classes in this scenario) the select works like you'd expect. Then when I change the types to only TextSectionDTO and TextSection (changing the abstracts back), the select doesn't work anymore.

I'd like a solution so that I can get this to work with the construction I have right now, though I'm more interested in why this does not work the way it is. Even if I can get this to work I'll probably refactor this later.

Note:

- I'm targeting MVC 4.5 (so the compiler is not some old version not being able to infer, which was the solution to some similar questions on here).
- The switch clause has a default case, i.e. the error shouldn't be able to be caused by a path not returning a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyText:
    return new TextSection((TextSectionDTO) s);
case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyImage:
    return new ImageSection((ImageSectionDTO) s);
```

These two cases return differen types. The compiler isn´t smart enough to check if those types derive from the same base-type so you have to cast them explicitely:

```
case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyText:
    return (SectionDTO) new TextSection((TextSectionDTO) s);
case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyImage:
    return (SectionDTO) new ImageSection((ImageSectionDTO) s);
```

Why this isn´t implemented on the compiler? I assume this is because the compiler has to check for many different types. Assume that your two types `Foo1` and `Foo2` do not directly derive from `Bar` but from two different ones (`Bar1` and `Bar2` accordingly) that themselfs inherit from `Bar`. Now the compiler should check if `Foo1` and `Foo2` can be assigned to any common base-class which they can not, and also check if they derive from something that HAS a common base-class (`Bar`). In the end we had to check the whole inheritance-chain until `object`, not mentioning any interfaces which should also be checked.

```
class Foo1 : Bar1 {}
class Foo2 : Bar2 {}

class Bar1 : Bar {}
class Bar2 : Bar {}
```

Comment: Okay, this worked, pasted 'as Section' behind both returns. Why do I need to do this though? Shouldn't the fact that they both derive from Section be enough given the fact that I'm returning a List of Sections in the method the expression is in?

Comment: I suppose this is because if the compiler WOULD check for the whole inheritance-chain this may take several loops on the whole chain. Assuem you´d have a much deeper chain. Now the compiler should check against all interfaces and base-classes mentioned in the whole chain which might take too long.

Comment: They both also inherit from `object`.

Comment: There is a similar check in place for array declarations: `new [] { a, b, c }`. If `a`, `b`, and `c` are distinct types, the rule is that if one of those types is a base type for the others, then that type will be used, otherwise you get a compiler error. Sure, it *could*  pick `object` always but in the end it is better to be explicit.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That´s a good analogon, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks that does make sense. I just got confused because it seemed to me that select knows it I need a List of Sections, but considering bigger inheritance chains makes it clear.

Answer (score 3):

`Select` method has two type aguments - `TSource` and `TResult`. Since you are invoking it on `IEnumerable<SectionDTO>`, `TSource` is inferred to be `SectionDTO`, so `ss.Select((SectionDTO s) =>` is not needed and can be just `ss.Select(s => ...`.

The problem is the `TResult` which in your case cannot be inferred. Why? You have two returns - `TextSection` and `ImageSection`. They are not the same and none of them is a base of the another. What do you think the compiler should infer? You think that the answer should be the common base type `Section`, but the same could apply to a common base `object` or any common base class/interface of the two type. In other words, the result is ambiguous, so instead of guessing what is your intention, the compiler requires you to specify that explicitly. Similar to ternary operator `? :` it would be sufficient to specify the common base in just one branch, so the following should resolve it

```
var viewModels = ss.Select(s =>
{
    switch (s.SectionType)
    {
        case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyText:
            return (Section)new TextSection((TextSectionDTO) s);
        case Enums.SectionTypes.OnlyImage:
            return new ImageSection((ImageSectionDTO) s);
        default:
            throw new Exception("This section does not exist - FIXME");
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This explanation is very useful as well, I understand it now. Thanks.